# rolling join with cumulative application in data.table R

Tags: r, join, data.table

I have two `data.table` objects. One objects contains data (`a`) every June or every year. The other contains data (`b`) every month of every year. I would like to join them, rolling the `a` forward. However, I would like to multiply by the cumulative sum of `b` since the last date that `a` was available. Here is an example:

```
dt1 = data.table(a = c(1,2,1), t = c(1, 12, 24))
dt2 = data.table(b = 1:24, t = seq(from = 1, to = 24, by = 1))
```

The joined result should look like:

```
 t  a  b
 1  1  1
 2  3  2
 3  6  3
 4 10  4
...
11 66 11
12  2 12
13 15 13
14 29 14
...
```

Notice that the next time `a` is actually available, that is the value used in the join.

Comment: Can you provide more or your desired result, at least a few after t = 12. Do you restart the cumsum?

Comment: yes, restart the cumsum. added more info.

Comment: Not sure, maybe something like `res <- dt1[dt2, on = "t", roll = TRUE][, a := cumsum(c(a[1L], b[-1L])), by = a]` ?

Comment: problem with that is it assumes `a` is unique. it's true in this toy example but not generally

Comment: yes, that's my current thought is to use the interval as the index. i was hoping something with overlapping joins would do the trick but i can't quite figure it out

Comment: with the devel version `dt1[dt2, on = 't', roll = T, .(a, b, t, x.t)]` will contain all of the information you need

Comment: unfortunately can't get the development version on my cluster here. any way to do it with the latest release?

Comment: Maybe make your example reproducible then? You don't really need 24 rows in `dt2` btw, you could significantly make it shorter while also adding some rows to `dt1` so `a` won't be unique. Also, when responding to people in comments, please use @ with their name attached to it, otherwise we need to keep in mind checking up on this thread all the time.